# when i run an app it open for a short seconded then close instantly. i am working in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working in visual studio 2015. When I run the code to make an xamarin android app it open and close instantly. It happens with out warning and I found no solution for this so far. I all ways had to make new project but recently it happening a lot. I am running the code off my phone.

I tried clean and rebuild. turning ever thing off and on again. I deleted ever trace of it off my phone and still does not work.

I am out of idea what to try. I really need help if any one know the solution to this. If you need any more details, just comment.

Update:
the device log are

> Time  Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
> 03-09 14:17:12.996  HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 ConnectivityService
> getActiveNetworkInfo called by com.htc.ptg (950/10171)
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.966 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiNative-wlan0       returned true
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.956 HTC Desire 620  Debug   18039   wpa_supplicant  WiFioffload: SignalStrength: =25
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.956 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiNative-wlan0    doBoolean: SignalStrength 25
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.956 HTC Desire 620  Warning 840 WifiHW  QCOM Debug wifi_send_command "IFNAME=wlan0 SignalStrength 25"
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.956 HTC Desire 620  Info    18039   wpa_supplicant  Recv Cmd 1: IFNAME=wlan0
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.946 HTC Desire 620  Info    18039   wpa_supplicant  environment dirty rate=0 [0][0][0]
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.946 HTC Desire 620  Debug   18039   wpa_supplicant  nl80211: survey data missing!
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.946 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiStateMachine    fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative mLinkspeedCount = 2, mLinkspeedSum: 172
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.946 HTC Desire 620  Error   18039   wpa_supplicant  send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 50
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.946 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiStateMachine    fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -51 abnormalRssiCnt = 0 newLinkSpeed = 86
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.946 HTC Desire 620  Error   18039   wpa_supplicant  send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 5
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.946 HTC Desire 620  Error   18039   wpa_supplicant  send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 17
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.926 HTC Desire 620  Warning 840 WifiHW  QCOM Debug wifi_send_command "IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL"
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.926 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiNative-wlan0    doString: SIGNAL_POLL
>
> 03-09 14:17:12.926 HTC Desire 620  Info    18039   wpa_supplicant  Recv Cmd 1: IFNAME=wlan0
>
> 03-09 14:17:11.946 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 ConnectivityService getActiveNetworkInfo called by com.htc.ptg (950/10171)
>
> 03-09 14:17:10.966 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 ConnectivityService getActiveNetworkInfo called by com.htc.ptg (950/10171)
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.946 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 ConnectivityService getActiveNetworkInfo called by com.htc.ptg (950/10171)
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.896 HTC Desire 620  Info    18039   wpa_supplicant  Recv Cmd 1: IFNAME=wlan0
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.896 HTC Desire 620  Warning 840 WifiHW  QCOM Debug wifi_send_command "IFNAME=wlan0 SignalStrength 25"
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.896 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiNative-wlan0       returned true
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.896 HTC Desire 620  Debug   18039   wpa_supplicant  WiFioffload: SignalStrength: =25
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.886 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiNative-wlan0    doBoolean: SignalStrength 25
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.886 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiStateMachine    fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative mLinkspeedCount = 1, mLinkspeedSum: 86
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.876 HTC Desire 620  Error   18039   wpa_supplicant  send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 17
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.876 HTC Desire 620  Info    18039   wpa_supplicant  environment dirty rate=0 [1][0][0]
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.876 HTC Desire 620  Error   18039   wpa_supplicant  send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 5
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.876 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiStateMachine    fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -51 abnormalRssiCnt = 0 newLinkSpeed = 86
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.876 HTC Desire 620  Info    18039   wpa_supplicant  Recv Cmd 1: IFNAME=wlan0
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.876 HTC Desire 620  Error   18039   wpa_supplicant  send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 50
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.876 HTC Desire 620  Debug   18039   wpa_supplicant  nl80211: survey data missing!
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.866 HTC Desire 620  Warning 840 WifiHW  QCOM Debug wifi_send_command "IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL"
>
> 03-09 14:17:09.866 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiNative-wlan0    doString: SIGNAL_POLL
>
> 03-09 14:17:08.946 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 ConnectivityService getActiveNetworkInfo called by com.htc.ptg (950/10171)
>
> 03-09 14:17:07.946 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 ConnectivityService getActiveNetworkInfo called by com.htc.ptg (950/10171)
>
> 03-09 14:17:06.966 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 ConnectivityService getActiveNetworkInfo called by com.htc.ptg (950/10171)
>
> 03-09 14:17:06.866 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiStateMachine    [ScoreAP] + current TXpacket:13173, mTXpacketCount:13171, avgLinkspeed:86,mAvgTxRate86
>
> 03-09 14:17:06.866 HTC Desire 620  Debug   840 WifiStateMachine    [ScoreAP] + TX packet didn't send enough number, don't update TX rate in DB
>
> 03-09 14:17:06.856 HTC Desire 620  Debug   18039   wpa_supplicant  WiFioffload: SignalStrength: =25
>
> 03-09 14:17:06.856 HTC Desire 620  Info    18039   wpa_supplicant  Recv Cmd 1: IFNAME=wlan0

Comment: try to add some Try / Catch. In Xamarin Studio exists an Application Output TAB where App writes a lot of logs, also for exception. I think there should be something similar in Visual Studio.

Comment: - Through Android SDK manager update your Platform SDK for whatever API you're targeting, as well as SDK Tools, Platform Tools, and Build Tools.  Then update your nuget packages.  Then double check your API Target and minimum version.  Rebuild.  Uninstall any test versions of app from your device.  And Test.  If all that fails, attach the Application output and Android Device Log here for better feedback.

Comment: thanks. i will do that know. how much of the log do you want to see

Comment: what does this mean
`Time Device Name Type PID Tag Message
03-09 14:16:54.646 HTC Desire 620 Error 18039 wpa_supplicant send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 50

03-09 14:16:54.646 HTC Desire 620 Error 18039 wpa_supplicant send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 17

03-09 14:16:54.646 HTC Desire 620 Error 18039 wpa_supplicant send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 5`

Comment: Does this happen with empty projects? Could you show us the code? Specifically the first constructors that are hit? I had the same issue a while back and it turned out to be a logical error in the constructor of the second VM. Wrapping it in a try catch block caught it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, just back into work today. yeah the code is fine, because it was working earlier that day but after it just seem to break. the first page was never changed. this problem has happened with basic code before too